# PhantomJS pass argument to evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

I have a small test app using NightmareJS as a wrapper for PhantomJS I want to test for the existence of a class on an element. I have this code:

```
new Nightmare()
  .goto(baseURL)
  .evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('body');
  }, function(element) {
    element.className.should.equal(expected)
    callback();
  })
  .run();
```

How can I pass an argument to the querySelector method rather than hardcoding the tag?

I have tried

```
var tag = body;
new Nightmare()
      .goto(baseURL)
      .evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector(tag);
      }, function(element) {
        element.className.should.equal(expected)
        callback();
      })
      .run();
```

However PhantomJS always returns an error that it cannot find the variable.

How can I accomplish passing a variable argument to the querySelector method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts. The DOM context (or page context) is sandboxed and is only accessible through `evaluate()`. `evaluate()` takes a function that is evaluated in the page, so the code inside cannot reference any variables or functions that are defined outside of it.

The [signature of Nightmare's `evaluate()` function](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/e0da369c348a69f2c4b2eeca75f0e9722c3ee743/lib/actions.js#L395) is the following:

```
function evaluate(func, callback/**, arg1, arg2...*/)
```

It means that additional values can be passed directly into the function as additional arguments. `func`, `callback` and `arg1`, `arg2`, ... are passed through [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) (which is used by Nightmare to actually interface with PhantomJS) and `func`, `arg1`, `arg2`, ... are then passed to [PhantomJS's `evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Proper usage would be:

```
var tag = "body";
new Nightmare()
  .goto(baseURL)
  .evaluate(function(innertag) {
    return document.querySelector(innertag).className;
  }, function(className) {
    className.should.equal(expected);
    callback();
  }, tag)
  .run();
```